# Licensing using openWRT opkg

Tags: openwrt, buildroot

We are planning to use openWRT "Attitude Adjustment" for out development. We have some software which we need to commercially license ; Is it possible to use opkg to license them commercially ? Is there any document which tells me licensing policies of opkg with respect to commercial code ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use the Attitude Adjustment buildroot and combine it with OpenWRT packages that have a different licence than the GPL.
The important part is that you have to release a GPL tarball to all the GPL stuff that you are using and evertually you have modified. The proprietary part can be released in binary form, if it is a package that is totally independent from previous sources.

I will make an example. Ubiquiti releases a firmware for its devices that is OpenWRT based. Ubiquiti releases a GPL tarball that contains the source code of everything that was GPL and inherited from OpenWRT. The binary blobs of software developed from scratch by ubiquiti are not released as source code.

Answer (score 0):

[it's GPL](http://code.google.com/p/opkg/source/browse/trunk/COPYING)

so i guess it's a bad news for you.

You can always contact the author/s to see if they want to change their license.